# Excel keyboard shortcut for filtering changed

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a problem with my Excel, as of today the shortcut for filtering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> does not work for me anymore. Instead of setting the filter, my excel now zooms in. Did anyone have similar problem?

I work on Excel 2010 and it's not my private PC so I'm not able to install 3rd party software, edit registry, etc... but I have access to Control Panel.

Comment: Use the key sequence - `ALT`+`D`+`F`+`F` to add the filter if you cannot make any changes to your PC. Thanks for the `Ctrl + Shift + L` tip. I didn't know

Comment: I am using 2010 also and am unable to duplicate the same problem. My keyboard shortcut works as it should.